# FME autoincrement id is not recognized

Tags: postgis, fme-form

I have made a workflow in which I pass some data from a shapefile to a PostGIS database using FME 2015. The table in the database has several columns and one of them is an id with an auto-increment primary key.

Everything was working just fine till last week but now that I tried to rerun the process I get this error:

```
Bulk copy failed on table 'public.foc_network_rural' using delimiter ':'. Error was 'ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
 CONTEXT:  COPY foc_network_rural, line 1: "NULL:NULL:MT:RR1393RETH:010200002034080000BC0400002DE7BAF24C2521416DCF4D428CD44D41D9757D684C25...'
```

So for some reason the auto-increment functionality is not recognized or doesn't work.

Any idea what can cause this error?

Comment: bulk copy is being done via FME from shapefile to PostGIS table?  I would think those structures need to be the same.  Is it possible last time around you dropped the id column and readded it after the bulk copy?

Comment: It appears that there are null values in your ID field where there shouldn't be.  Have you checked the ID field in the shapefile that there are indeed no missing values?

Comment: @Fezter My shape file doesn't have an ID field. I have created the ID field with autoincrement functionality in my postgis database.

Comment: @LR1234567 I haven't dropped the ID column. Actually I haven't changed anything in the structure of the table. Perhaps only I used pgadmin in order to create a backup of the table. Would this affect the procedure? It seems like that values are not auto incremented. I have created one new column with "serial" and it works ok. But if I make it Primary key then I get the same error.

Comment: are you using INSERT or UPDATE in the FME PostGIS writer?

Comment: I am using INSERT.